# Mover archivos dependiendo de su fecha en Python

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo mover/copiar un archivo que contiene ("archivoYYMMDD") a su respectiva carpeta que contiene el nombre del Mes (January,February,etc..) en Python?

Actualmente el codigo de fechas se lo estoy concatenando con un bday para que solo tome días laborales:

```
day = days[0].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
```

Despues creo un arreglo con el nombre de los archivos

```
files = ['archivo1','archivo2','archivo3',etc...]
```

Hago un for en donde mando llamar el calendario con el mes y creo directorios en caso de no contar con ellos

```
for month in calendar.month_name[1:]:
    if not os.path.exists(directory+"\\"+month):
        os.makedirs(directory+"\\"+month)
```

Luego tomo los días y en un for lo concateno con los nombres

```
for x in day :
 for y in files :
  value = str(y)+str(x)
  shutil.copy(directory+"\\"+str(y)+".xlsx",directory+"\\"+month+"\\"+str(value)+".xlsx") //El tema aqui es que cuando lo corro se copia en c/u de los directorios sin tomar en cuenta el mes...
```

El tema que tengo es que antes del shutil quisiera saber si puedo mandarlos a la carpeta con su mes correspondiente...

El resultado que me sale ya con la concatenación es esta:

```
archivo120181212.xlsx
```

Y ahí sería el tomar el mes solamente, no se si tenga que hacerlo pasos atras o cómo...¿?

Comment: Hola Alan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Para que podamos ayudarte has de mostrar lo intentado y tus problemas concretos. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño script para mover los archivos pero te recomiendo usar timestamps porque si imprimes la fecha en un archivo no se puede parsear correctamente como lo hago aqui

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now().timestamp()
archivo = "Texto-{}.txt".format(time)
with open(archivo, "w") as f:
    f.write("Hola")
```

así puedes tener tu archivo formateado de forma correcta luego recuperamos el nombre en el caso de multiples archivos
y luego los mueves con shutil y haces un dict con los meses
    import os
    import shutil

```
meses = {"12":"diciembre"}
for i in os.listdir():
    if 'txt' in i:

    fecha = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float((nombre.split('-')[1]).replace('.txt','')))


    mestring = meses[str(fecha.month)]

    shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), nombre), os.path.join(os.getcwd(), mestring))
```

y esa seria la posible solucion a tu problema

Comment: Gracias por ayudar pero es mejor esperar a que el autor muestre un intento o investigacion realizada para asi ayudarle con sus problemas concretos y no hacerle la tarea sin más. Un saludo